# CSS/Javascript/Jquery: Show/Hide a DIV Depending on one of two images being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got 2 images, Image_A and Image_B. I also have 2 Div's, Div_A and Div_B which are both hidden when page loads.

If Image_A  is clicked, then I need show Div_A. But ig Image_B is then clicked I need to hide Div_A and show Div_B.

This should work the other way also, so there is only ever one div showing if an image is clicked

Can this be achieved with pure css only? Or if I do it in Javascript/Jquery???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may set your css as;

```
#img_1, #img_2{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

and in your JavaScript;

```
$('#img_1').click(function() {
  $('#div_1').css({"visibility":"visible"});
  $('#div_2').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});

$('#img_2').click(function() {
  $('#div_2').css({"visibility":"visible"});
  $('#div_1').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
});
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sxykk/)** is a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#img_1').on('click', function() {
  $('#div_1').show();
  $('#div_2').hide();
});

$('#img_2').on('click', function() {
  $('#div_1').hide();
  $('#div_2').show();
});
```

Comment: why bother using the ":visible" selector? i know you only want to hide them when they're visible, but wouldn't it be more efficient to have jquery "hide" them no matter what? instead of doing more processing in the selection stage? it really doesn't matter since this is such a simple task, just thought i'd throw it out there. and if you really wanted to go the ":visible" route, shouldn't you be checking for invisible divs on the .show() calls?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Javascript or Jquery by putting event handlers each image and changing the visibility of the divs in the called functions.

Not sure about doing it in pure css.